Why can’t the table I created be read and written?
I created a table with an empty table name
test ❯ create table ""(f1 bigint, tags(t1));
Query took 0.005 seconds.

But when I write data or query data, it fails.
test ❯ insert into ""(time, t1, f1) values(now(), 't11', 12);
422 Unprocessable Entity, details: {"error_code":"010001","error_message":"Datafusion: Error during planning: table_name cannot be empty"}
test ❯ \d
+------------+
| table_name |
+------------+
|            |
+------------+
Query took 0.005 seconds.

Is my table name Invalid? Or is there a problem with system processing?

Seems like an inconsistent implementation. Report a bug, and choose another table name.

The issue arises because you created a table with an empty name. While some database systems may technically allow this, it leads to significant problems when interacting with the table.

Rename the Table: If your database supports renaming tables, you can rename it to a valid name
ALTER TABLE "<TABLE_NAME>" RENAME TO valid_table_name;

Drop and Recreate the Table: If renaming isn't supported, you'll need to drop the table and create a new one with a valid name
DROP TABLE "<TABLE_NAME>"; 
CREATE TABLE valid_table_name (f1 BIGINT, tags(t1)); 



AI generated answer?
